# Windows 10 default store location

Tags: windows-10, default-settings, file-location

I am running on windows 10 in an entreprise and I have a network drive mapping my personal space on the server.

I observed that when I install any new software (not from the windows store), they are trying to write temporary files on the network drive. Even Visual Studio saves it's start up pages and templates on this network drive.

I guess that windows is setup to use this drive instead of "Documents" folder to store these files.

I had a look at the location in parameters->system->location and everything seems to be pointing to my c drive.

How could I change my setup to use "Documents" instead of my network drive to store these file?

Comment: Are you asking about changing the default location of the Windows Store directory or the default storage location?  Both make sense in the context of your question, you should edit your question, to make it clear what your asking.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i edited the question as suggested. The applications I try to add are not from the windows store. I removed my mapped drive and I try to install a PDF application. It complains that it cannot find the U: drive (which was mapped...). There's definitely something somewhere that says to use the U: drive instead of my local Documents folder

Comment: I have noticed this as well since Win 7.  I have my document moved to my H:. Adobe install for instance fails until I run an admin prompt and map the Admins H: to the same share.

Comment: The thing is that I want to use the Documents on my C, not on my network drive :-(

Comment: Where is your user profile stored?  If your profile was moved to the same network location that's the reason it's the default

Comment: when I cd to %userprofile%, it points to my folder on C: but your right, it looks like my profile is pointing to the network drive because it had created a MyDocument folder on the drive. I dont know how windows was installed and if the user profile was set upon installation. Is there any procedure to set the user profile to save on my C drive?

Answer (score 1):

In my Quick Access in file explorer, I had my U: displayed instead of Documents. I had to go to the Proprieties on U:, select location and change it to c:\users[username]\Documents. I still dont know why the Document folder was replaced by U: but this solved my problem. Thanks to Ramhound for his contribution to solve the problem.